# Testcafe: repeat click until another element appears

Tags: javascript, async-await, functional-testing, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm testing a user interface with testcafe.

The user is asked to click a button until a modal dialog appears, then it should click on a button in the dialog.

The number of clicks may vary in the test, sometimes is two, sometimes three. Thus, this code doesn't always work

```
await t
  .click(Button)
  .click(Button)
  .click(Button)
  .click(ModalDialogButton);
```

I need a way to repeatedly click `Button` until `ModalDialogButton` appears. Then, `ModalDialogButton` must be clicked.

How can I do this with testcafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to do this using the `while` loop like the following:

```
while (!(await ModalDialogButton.exists))
    await t.click(Button)

await t.click(ModalDialogButton);
```

Could you please clarify your need for repeatedly clicks? Maybe you can just wait for `ModalDialogButton` to exist. For example:

```
await ModalDialogButton();
```

This line automatically waits until the `ModalDialogButton` selector appears on the page with the default timeout. You can increase the [selector timeout](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#selector-timeout).

Comment: Thanks, the await solution made it!